# Simply where clause query of many columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to ask about this query if possible to simply it.

I have a table with some column like below:

```
class_01|class_02|class_03|class_04|class_05|class_06|class_07|class_08|class_09|
Sonto   | Botak  | Semut  | Setting|'<none>'|'<none>'|'<none>'|'<none>'|'<none>'|
```

Then I write a where clause like this:

```
SELECT bedrnr 
FROM   bedryf 
WHERE  class_01 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_02 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_03 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_04 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_05 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_06 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_07 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_08 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting') 
    OR class_09 IN ('Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting')
```

It's a where clause where the the value of IN is same there, but it just wanna find in 9 different column.
Any way for it to make query shorter?

Comment: It's a sign that the schema isn't well designed.There ought to be a single column containing `class` values, with one row per applicable class (and, if necessary, a constraint limiting the number of rows to 10), possibly as a separate table, if there are more columns you've not shown.

Comment: Can you have anything other than `'Sonto', 'Botak',  'Semut', 'Setting', '<none>'` in your 9 columns? and what do you mean by `'<none>'`? is it empty string or null or '<none>'?

Comment: <none> is default value when DB was created. Its mean no data yet, and <none> will be eliminated by C# logic when composing the query.

Comment: You didn't answer the first question. Also, What is your requirement? Are you trying to select records at least one column has data not equal to `<none>` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select distinct bedrnr
FROM   bedryf unpivot (value for class in (class_01, class_02, class_03, class_04, class_05, class_06, class_07, class_08, class_09)) b
inner join (
    values ('Sonto'), ('Botak'), ('Semut'), ('Setting') 
) t(thing) on b.value = t.thing
```

SQL Server 2005:

```
select distinct bedrnr
FROM   bedryf unpivot (value for class in (class_01, class_02, class_03, class_04, class_05, class_06, class_07, class_08, class_09)) b
inner join (
    select 'Sonto' as thing
    union all 
    select 'Botak' as thing
    union all
    select 'Semut' as thing
    union all
    select 'Setting' as thing
) t(thing) on b.value = t.thing
```

Answer (score 1):

You should fix your schema but another way (2008+ syntax)

```
SELECT bedrnr 
FROM   bedryf
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT class
               FROM   (VALUES(class_01),
                             (class_02),
                             (class_03),
                             (class_04),
                             (class_05),
                             (class_06),
                             (class_07),
                             (class_08),
                             (class_09)) V(class)
               WHERE  class IN ( 'Sonto', 'Botak', 'Semut', 'Setting' ))
```